# Designing a RCP-based application using the MVP pattern

Tags: design-patterns, eclipse-rcp, mvp, rcp

I am about to start the development of a medium-sized CRUD RCP-based application and I intend to use the MVP (model view presenter) pattern.

I understand that the main difference between the MVP and the MVC is that the presenter updates the view whereas the controller doesn't.

What I really don't understand is who has a reference to what in this pattern. In one tutorial, I read that the view has a presenter instance variable (see: http://www.logicdevelopment.net/blog/?p=16). But the presenter also needs to have a reference to the view. Doesn't it? Is all of this correct?

Can anyone please provide explanations of how a typical MVP application is structured in terms of who owns references to what?

code added from the view:

```
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                // can we reference the presenter here? how?
            }
        });
```

Using information from link provided below I came up with the diagram below. Notice that the view has a reference to the presenter and vice versa (see option one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248992/does-presenter-in-model-view-presenter-create-views/6431252#6431252)):

[image: passive view diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are two different flavors of MVP. The MVP pattern was described by Fowler in 2004 and he [retired it in 2006](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html) by splitting the pattern into [supervising conroller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) (sc) and [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html) (pv). In sc, the view is bound to the model and in pv not, in pv the view is only changed by the presenter directly.

My answer to [Does Presenter in Model-View-Presenter create views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248992/does-presenter-in-model-view-presenter-create-views/6431252#6431252) has some more details.

Comment: Thanks Marijn. I have added code in my post. To refine my question: what should go `\\here` in terms of the presenter/controller? Can the view have a reference to the presenter/controller for instance? I don't seem to see anything indicating this in either of the sc or pv...

Comment: A view can have events, that the presenter subscribes to. You can also have the view hold a reference to the presenter (knowing only of its interface type). In the latter situation, vuew and presenter hold a reference to each other, which leads to the question [Does Presenter in Model-View-Presenter create views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248992/does-presenter-in-model-view-presenter-create-views/6431252#6431252).

Comment: Ok. Can you confirm only option 1 of you post applies here in the case of RCP - because the creation of views is not really under my control?

Comment: Confirmed, assuming that the creation of the view is not under your control and with the disclaimer that I know close-to-nothing about rcp. E.g. RCP might provide you with an option to interact with the "view creation bootstrapper", which would leave option 3 open too. I applied MVP to winforms applications, where I encountered similar problems: namely that winform infrastructure places some requirements on construction and destruction of the view. In those cases, creating my own bootstrapper for the mvp triad really helped.